# python mysql Incorrect string value warning

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to enter values into a mysql db using python. To this end, I have something like:

```
import MySQLdb
variables=[]*10 #list of variables.
n=len(variables)

#create python-mysql cursor connection
..
#load values into mysql:
for i in range(0,n):
    cursor.executemany(sql, variables[i])
```

This shoots out some errors in rows (approx 1% of the rows):

```
Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xA2\xD0\xB5\xD0\xBA...' for column 'Link' at row 395
cursor.executemany(sql, variables[i])
mergeDB.py:85: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x91\xD0\xB8\xD1\x82...' for column 'Link' at row 431
cursor.executemany(sql, variables[i])
mergeDB.py:85: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x91\xD0\xB8\xD1\x82...' for column 'Link' at row 568
cursor.executemany(sql, variables[i])
mergeDB.py:85: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xA7\xD0\xB5\xD0\xBB...' for column 'Link' at row 665
cursor.executemany(sql, variables[i])
mergeDB.py:85: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x96\xD0\xB5\xD0\xBB...' for column 'Link' at row 827
cursor.executemany(sql, variables[i])
mergeDB.py:85: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x9B\xD1\x8E\xD0\xB1...' for column 'Link' at row 1242
cursor.executemany(sql, variables[i])
mergeDB.py:85: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xA2\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB9...' for column 'Link' at row 1310
cursor.executemany(sql, variables[i])
mergeDB.py:85: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x9B\xD1\x8E\xD0\xB1...' for column 'Link' at row 1468
cursor.executemany(sql, variables[i])
mergeDB.py:85: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x94\xD0\xBD\xD0\xB5...' for column 'Link' at row 1687
cursor.executemany(sql, variables[i])
mergeDB.py:85: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x91\xD0\xB5\xD1\x81...' for column 'Link' at row 1848
cursor.executemany(sql, variables[i])
```

From  previous SOF threads, I have tried using inside my python file:

```
ALTER TABLE dbx.tablex MODIFY Link VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8; COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

but this gives me an error:

```
ALTER TABLE dbx.tablex MODIFY Link VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8; COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How does one solve this problem? How can I simply delete (tell python not to load the rows) the rows which have the "Incorrect String Value?" within this loop:

```
for i in range(0,n):
    cursor.executemany(sql, variables[i])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE dbx.tablex MODIFY Link VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8; COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

This is a MySQL query, not a Python statement. You need to pass the above to MySQL.

Also, `[] * 10` does not do what you think it does. And the proper way to iterate over a list of variables is:

```
for variable in variables:
    cursor.execute(sql, variable)
```

But you can do this directly:

```
cursor.executemany(sql, variables)
```

Comment: Rob, OK. but when I execute the mySQL query (in mySQL), the problem with Incorrect String Value still remains. []*10 was just a quick one I write for the post.